# How to read web.config of different project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

In my Solution I have two projects-1. A WCF service, 2. A Class Library.
The WCF service has a project reference of the class library. I want to read the configurationsection of web.config in my class library. How is that possible?

N.B. Note that where the WCF service is published is not known.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a reference to `System.Configuration` in your references folder. You should definitely be using the `ConfigurationManager` over the obsolete `ConfigurationSettings.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read only the [app keys](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20817/Manage-Web-config-from-XML-File-by-using-configSou), you can try,

```
<appSettings configSource="fie_path_of_another_project">
```